# Create a vector by repeating values in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm banging my head against the wall for this. It must be so easy, but in my 7+ years of R coding I never had to do this, and I can't figure out how to do it now.

Here's a toy df:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> y <- c(2,3,4)
> TRY <- as.data.frame(x,y)
```

I want to see a brand new vector (in a df or just as a vector, whatever) that has the value "1" repeated 2 times, and then "2" repeated 3 times, and then "3" repeated 4 times.

That's all I want. Can someone PLEASE help me?

I thought of melt and cast and all that, but I don't think they're what I need here.

Thanks!
Divya

Comment: does `rep(x,y)` work?

Comment: YESSS thank you so much! I forgot about rep()

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer to help future users.

You can get this effect using `rep` like so:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(2,3,4)
vec <- rep(x, y)
vec
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```